# React component not rerendering on redux state change of another container

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, react-redux, google-maps-react

I have two containers, namely: `FilterContainer` and `MapContainer`.

FilterContainer has a state: `selectedFitlers` which gets updated whenever user clicks on something from a list of checkboxes.

What `MapContainer` *should do*, is look at the `state.filterListContainer.selectedFilters` array and show up markers based on that.

But this isn't happening unfortunately. I see the changes being reflected in the redux state (by looking at the devTools), but somehow the `MapContainer` doesn't get notified of these changes. I tried to tap into the `componentWillReceiveProps` life-cycle hook, but don't see the `nextProps` get the new value.

Here is my code for the `MapContainer`:

https://gist.github.com/ghoshabhi/a275f923bba4a92b2b1f9dc3fbe09826#file-mapcontainer-index-jsx-L50

I don't understand why my container isn't rerendering or receiving updates about the change in the state in my redux store.

Any help/advice/alternative methods are welcome :)

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**
Redux devtools: 
[image]

Comment: Above you mention `state.filterContainer.selectedFilters`, but in the code it is `state.filterListContainer.selectedFilters`. Is this just a typo?

Comment: Hello @Martin! Yes, it should be `state.filterListContainer.selectedFilters`. I will update the question! Thank you

Comment: I can share more code, if needed :)

Comment: What does the code that renders the MapContainer look like?

Comment: @Martin: Map.jsx: https://gist.github.com/ghoshabhi/b714bde7732df7c26df120b6348b4039

Comment: How about FilterContainer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146579/discussion-between-abhishek-ghosh-and-martin).

Answer (score 0):

I looked into your code and I noticed that in the FilterContainer component you commented the selectedFilters PropTypes, while it's still in place in MapContainer component. Try to comment it in FilterContainer too in order to see if it works. It could be an issue of incorrect type.